# JavaScript: better/cleaner functional way to find item from a nested array

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I am trying to write a find function to find items from matched items from a potentially nested array (*without* having to flat the array first) and I am trying to write in a FP way.

Here is my attempt:

```js
const nestedArray = [
  [{ id: 1 }],
  [{ id: 2 }],
  [{ id: 3 }, [{ id: 4 }]],
  { id: 5 },
]

function findTarget(arr, predicate) {
  const helper = ([x, ...xs]) =>
    x === undefined
      ? null
      : predicate(x)
      ? x
      : Array.isArray(x)
      ? helper(x) ?? helper(xs)
      : helper(xs)

  return helper(arr)
}

findTarget(nestedArray, (item) => item.id === 5)
```

I think it works but it is not super readable and I am sure there are better ways to write such a function.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I would implement this using recursion:

```js
function findTarget(value, predicate) {
  const isArray = Array.isArray(value);

  // Base case: if value is not array and predicate matches, we found a match
  if (!isArray) {
    if (predicate(value)) return value;
    return null;
  }

  // value must be an array, so run recursion and see if value exists
  for (const item of value) {
    const foundItem = findTarget(item, predicate);
    if (foundItem !== null) {
      return foundItem;
    }
  }

  // nothing found
  return null;
}
```

does the same thing that your code does and imo looks cleaner.

Comment: This seems to return an array from the for loop, if item is another nested array. Not sure if this is intended. You should rather return whatever the recursive call returns

Comment: @WiktorZychla good catch, I just needed to set `foundItem = findTarget(item, predicate)` and return the `foundItem` if not null. Edited answer

Comment: Credited you in advance, regards.

Comment: Btw OP is calling `predicate(value)` even when it `isArray` and only falls back to iterating when it didn't match, you might want to keep that behaviour

Comment: hey thanks for the solution. but I was actually looking for something that uses functional programming

Answer (score 2):

Since your example is calling `predicate(x)` in the first place, it will return a false positive when matching an `array` with an `id: 5` property, so the `Array.isArray(x)` should go first to avoid this:

```js
const nestedArray = [
  Object.assign([{ id: 1 }], { id: 5 }),
  [{ id: 2 }],
  [{ id: 3 }, [{ id: 4 }], null, [[{ id: 5 }]]],
  { id: 6 },
]

function findTargetLoop (arr, match) {
  if (!Array.isArray(arr))
    return arr && match(arr) ? arr : null;
  let item, i = 0;
  while (!(item = findTargetLoop(arr[i++], match)) && i < arr.length);
  return item ?? null;
}

const findTargetFunc = (arr, match, next) =>
  (next = ([item, ...rest]) =>
    Array.isArray(item) ? next(item) ?? next(rest)
    : item && match(item) ? item
    : rest.length ? next(rest) : null)(arr);


const match = item => item.id === 5;

console.log('with iterations', findTargetLoop(nestedArray, match));

console.log('pure functional', findTargetFunc(nestedArray, match));
```

Comment: sorry I am not sure if I understand exactly what the false positive means here? can you give me an example?

Comment: @Joji Just replace the `findTarget` function here with yours and check the result.

Comment: got it thanks for pointing that out!  but I was actually looking for something that uses functional programming

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach I can think of. It uses the `init` function as a sentinel value to distinguish whether the element being searched for has already been found. Before returning, it invokes the accumulated value which is either `() => undefined`, or `() => curr` capturing the first element that matches the predicate.

```js
const flatFind = (array, predicate) => {
  const init = () => undefined
  const reducer = (prev, curr) => (
    prev === init
    ? Array.isArray(curr)
      ? curr.reduce(reducer, init)
      : predicate(curr)
        ? () => curr
        : init
    : prev
  )
  return array.reduce(reducer, init)()
}

const nestedArray = [
  [{ id: 1 }],
  [{ id: 2 }],
  [{ id: 3 }, [{ id: 4 }]],
  { id: 5 },
]

console.log(flatFind(nestedArray, item => item.id === 5))
```

Comment: why did you make `init` and `curr` a function when they can just be a value. e.g. Your `init` can just be a string `init` and it seems like that would work the same.

Comment: @Joji the idea is to create a value that can't possibly be confused with user data. Only an object or function created within the scope of `flatFind` would satisfy that requirement. And a function is convenient to avoid conditional logic for the default value if no elements satisfy the predicate.

Comment: hmm what's wrong with `init` just being `null` or `undefined` instead of a function returning a `undefined`? still trying to understand this

Comment: @Joji because `null` or `undefined` could be a valid element in an array, and `prev === init` would erroneously return `true` even if a match was already found.

Answer (score 0):

Your form is a good start but the `helper` is unnecessary and the order of conditions should be changed. Here we use [inductive reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) -

1. If `x` is undefined, there is nothing left to match. Return no match.
2. (inductive) `x` is defined. If `x` is an array, find within `x` or find within `xs`
3. (inductive) `x` is defined and `x` is a non-array. If `x` matches predicate `f`, return the match
4. (inductive) `x` is defined and `x` is a non-array that does not match the predicate `f`. Find within the sub-problem, `xs`.

```js
const find = ([x, ...xs], f) =>
  x === undefined                 // 1
    ? null
: Array.isArray(x)                // 2
    ? find(x, f) ?? find(xs, f)
: f(x)                            // 3
    ? x
: find(xs, f)                     // 4

const t = [
  [{ id: 1 }],
  [{ id: 2 }],
  [{ id: 3 }, [{ id: 4 }]],
  { id: 5 },
]

console.log(find(t, (item) => item?.id === 5)) // { id: 5 }
console.log(find(t, (item) => item?.id === 9)) // null
```

Note, the behavior of your `findTarget` checks child arrays against the predicate and allows for return of arrays that match the predicate. This is inconsistent behaviour as it's not possible to match the outermost array and the predicate checks for `.id` properties on arrays. The `find` solution above avoids this by changing the order of conditions 2 and 3. If you want the ability to return array matches with your function, you can change the order to 1,3,2,4.

Comment: This won't work if there is an `undefined` gap in the array, e.g. `, ,`, preceding the matched item.

Comment: @n-- true, `undefined` values cause undefined behaviour! If you have `undefined` values leaking into this function, the actual problem exists elsewhere in your program.